# asp.net: Is there a way to suppress HTML output of "ID" attribute when using runat="server"?

Tags: asp.net, html

The new .NET v4 offers some great ways to customise output of control IDs, so they're clean and easier to use with JavaScript.

However, I'd sometimes like to completely suppress the output of a control's ID in the HTML. Is that possible, on a per-control basis?

eg:

```
<div class="myclass" id="mycontrol" runat="server">
  ... some HTML
</div>
```

I want to conditionally control output (visibility) of "mycontrol" in the codebehind. But, when it *is* visible, I want the HTML output to be simply:

```
<div class="myclass">
  ... some HTML
</div>
```

Do we have that level of control in .NET 4?
I mean *directly and easily*, ie. without wrapping it in a Placeholder or doing custom rendering.

Answer (score 1):

you can use combination of asp. net and jquery for your top part you can do this if you are using .net 4.0

```
<div class="myclass" ClientIDMode="Static" id="mycontrol" runat="server">
  ... some HTML
</div>
```

and with jquery  you can

```
$(".myclass").removeAttr("id")
```

and remove more unnecessary attributes

```
<div class="myclass">
  ... some HTML
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's true, but isn't what I'm after.. I'm looking for a way to suppress output of the ID in the HTML sent to the browser.

Comment: I was hoping there was a property where you could specify, for example, `IDLocation="ServerOnly"`. That would be awesome, but I'm probably asking too much. :)